# IOS App search error при нажатии на кнопку поиска

Tags: ios, search

Делаю приложение по туториалу "Rick and Morty". В приложении когда в инпуте в разделе "Characters" ввожу например имя персонажа и нажимаю на кнопку search в правом верхнем угле то выдает ошибку

```
2023-06-20 21:27:47.054256+0300 RickAndMorty[80533:7606900] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _performAfterCATransactionCommitsWithLegacyRunloopObserverBasedTiming:block:], UIApplication.m:3351
2023-06-20 21:27:47.090145+0300 RickAndMorty[80533:7606900] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Call must be made on main thread'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010616a330 __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001051a5274 objc_exception_throw + 56
    2   Foundation                          0x00000001084ec9b4 _userInfoForFileAndLine + 0
    3   UIKitCore                           0x000000012df39e2c -[UIApplication _performAfterCATransactionCommitsWithLegacyRunloopObserverBasedTiming:block:] + 380
    4   UIKitCore                           0x000000012da1d3a0 -[UIFocusSystem _focusEnvironmentWillBecomeInvisible:] + 124
    5   UIKitCore                           0x000000012e3d07cc -[UIView(Rendering) setHidden:] + 444
    6   UIKit                               0x0000000148c64868 -[UIViewAccessibility setHidden:] + 72
    7   RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad727c $s12RickAndMorty19RMSearchResultsViewC015setUpCollectionF033_3E109A3D89FDB55CDF0AAF9F712DC783LLyyF + 72
    8   RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad717c $s12RickAndMorty19RMSearchResultsViewC07processF5Model33_3E109A3D89FDB55CDF0AAF9F712DC783LLyyF + 296
    9   RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad6148 $s12RickAndMorty19RMSearchResultsViewC9viewModel33_3E109A3D89FDB55CDF0AAF9F712DC783LLAA0d6ResultfH0OSgvW + 28
    10  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad6248 $s12RickAndMorty19RMSearchResultsViewC9viewModel33_3E109A3D89FDB55CDF0AAF9F712DC783LLAA0d6ResultfH0OSgvs + 132
    11  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad7b40 $s12RickAndMorty19RMSearchResultsViewC9configure4withyAA0d6ResultF5ModelO_tF + 64
    12  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104b0452c $s12RickAndMorty12RMSearchViewC13setUpHandlers33_0271459AF63E074C028F4E69B1A73B35LL9viewModelyAA0deeR0C_tFyAA0d6ResulteR0OcfU0_ + 372
    13  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104ad01b4 $s12RickAndMorty012RMSearchViewE5ModelC20processSearchResults33_83F2D7930585F215B1FC902CD1CCB9E7LL5modelySe_SEp_tF + 2064
    14  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104acf8b0 $s12RickAndMorty012RMSearchViewE5ModelC17makeSearchAPICall33_83F2D7930585F215B1FC902CD1CCB9E7LL_7requestyxm_AA9RMRequestCtSeRzSERzlFys6ResultOyxs5Error_pGcfU_ + 476
    15  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104b1015c $s12RickAndMorty9RMServiceC7execute_9expecting10completionyAA9RMRequestC_xmys6ResultOyxs5Error_pGctSeRzSERzlFy10Foundation4DataVSg_So13NSURLResponseCSgsAK_pSgtYbcfU_ + 1232
    16  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104b1042c $s12RickAndMorty9RMServiceC7execute_9expecting10completionyAA9RMRequestC_xmys6ResultOyxs5Error_pGctSeRzSERzlFy10Foundation4DataVSg_So13NSURLResponseCSgsAK_pSgtYbcfU_TA + 72
    17  RickAndMorty                        0x0000000104afb3f0 $s10Foundation4DataVSgSo13NSURLResponseCSgs5Error_pSgIeghggg_So6NSDataCSgAGSo7NSErrorCSgIeyBhyyy_TR + 280
    18  CFNetwork                           0x00000001099a2cf8 CFNetwork + 27896
    19  CFNetwork                           0x00000001099be170 _CFHTTPMessageSetResponseProxyURL + 14628
    20  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107560528 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    21  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107561d50 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    22  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010756a014 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 924
    23  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000010756ada4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 480
    24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000107578b74 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 1716
    25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b1834878 _pthread_wqthread + 284
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001b183363c start_wqthread + 8
)
libc++abi: terminating due to uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

вот репозиторий с кодом. Помогите исправить ошибку пожалуйста

https://github.com/SashaMaksyutenko/RickAndMortyIOSApp